# Splitting Numpy arrays based on its elements, where each element of the array is unique

Tags: python, numpy, vector, split

I have a Numpy 1D vector, for example `x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1]`

I have to perform a splitting of it into n subarrays, where each vector must start with a new value and continue for as long as the value is the same, such that the final answer is `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [1], [3, 3], [1]]`.

I do understand that I have to use `numpy.split()` function, but I have problems with finding the places at which the splitting must be done.

I humbly ask of your help, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to give `numpy.split` the indexes you need it to split the array

```
a = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,1,3,3,1])
np.split(a, np.argwhere(np.diff(a) != 0)[:,0] + 1)
# [array([1, 1, 1]), array([2, 2]), array([1]), array([3, 3]), array([1])]
```

---

**Details**

Using `np.diff(a)` you get the differences between each consecutive element

```
np.diff(a)
# array([ 0,  0,  1,  0, -1,  2,  0, -2])
```

The points where the differences are not equal to 0 is the points where the elements are not consecutively the same. Since you are looking for the indexes where the changes you need to do `np.diff(a) != 0` which returns:

```
np.diff(a) != 0
# array([False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True])
```

To convert the booleans into the indexes you can use [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)

```
np.argwhere(np.diff(a) != 0)
# array([[2],[4],[5],[7]])
# since we only need this for 1d arrays
np.argwhere(np.diff(a) != 0)[:,0]
# array([2, 4, 5, 7])
```

The you just use the aforementioned procedure to provide the correct indexes to `np.split`

```
np.split(a, np.argwhere(np.diff(a) != 0)[:,0])
# [array([1, 1]), array([1, 2]), array([2]), array([1, 3]), array([3, 1])]
```

Woops... wrong indexes... Seems we are off by 1 index. No problem, just add +1 to the results of `np.argwhere`

```
np.split(a, np.argwhere(np.diff(a) != 0)[:,0] + 1)
# [array([1, 1, 1]), array([2, 2]), array([1]), array([3, 3]), array([1])]
```